# умножить элементы массива scala

Tags: scala

Всем привет, есть массив (типа вектор), мне нужно узнать длину вектора, для этого нужно каждую координату умножить саму на себя, затем все их записать в новый массив, а уже у нового массива посчитать сумму элементов и взять оттуда квадратный корень
Пытаюсь сделать по вот такому (вроде логичному) алгоритму, но в `print` элементы остаются теми же что были, в чем может быть проблема?

```
var vector = Array(2, 2, 5)
var i = 0


for(x <- vector){
  var pr = x * x
  vector(i) = pr
  print(vector(i))
  print(i)
  i += 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ни в чем. Все в массиве меняется - и принт выдает правильный нечитаемый (так как пишется в одно слово без разделителей) ответ

Ну раз уж поставлен тэг `scala` - не надо так делать. По возможности избегать использования `var` и мутабельных структур

Идем по описанию

- у нас есть вектор. Коллекция чисел `v`
- нам надо произвести действие над каждым элементом - `map(f)` где f является функцией которая воплощает наше действие
- надо возвести в квадрат - `math.pow(<что>, <в какую степень>)`
- надо почитать сумму элементов коллекций - `collection.sum`
- надо взять корень - `math.sqrt(<число>)`

И соединяя все вместе получаем функцию:

```
def length(
  v: Array[Int] // входной аргумент
): Double = // возвращаемый тип
  math.sqrt( // корень
    v.map( // совершаем действие с каждым элементом коллекции
      math.pow(_, 2) // возведение в степень 2, подчеркивание 
        // является местом куда вставится текущий обрабатываемый 
        // элемент, эквивалентно записи `e => math.pow(e, 2)`
    ).sum // вычисляем сумму всех элементов
  )
```